# Save JAVA readed Image on CSHARP Server

Tags: java, c#, tcp, server, client

I am trying to save a Image from my JAVA-CLIENT on my CSHARP-SERVER.
I did following:

1. Read image as byte array (JAVA-CLIENT)
2. Convert byte array to base64 byte array (JAVA-CLIENT)
3. Send base64 byte array to CSHARP-SERVER (JAVA-CLIENT)
4. Receive base64 byte array (CSHARP-SERVER)
5. base64 byte array to base64 string (CSHARP-SERVER)
6. Decode base64 string to utf8 string (CSHARP-SERVER)
7. Get utf8 string bytes (CSHARP-SERVER)
8. Save bytes as image (CSHARP-SERVER)

Now I cant open this image file in my windows imageviewer..

But I noticed following:

- base64 string on csharp server is the same as on my client
- I compared both files(client and server).. opened them in notepad and saw that their not equal..

How can save this image on my server?
What is the best way to do this?
Is there maybe a open source java-csharp-bridge library?

Here is my code:

```
public class Program {


static String getBase64StringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    String b64 = null;
    try {
        //To Base64-String
        b64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes),"UTF-8");
        //UTF-8
        return b64;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //1.Read image as byte array
    byte[] data = FileManager.readeFile();
    //2.1 Convert byte array to base64 string
    String str64 = getBase64StringFromBytes(data);
    //2.2 Convert base64 string to base64 byte array
    byte[] b64Bytes = str64.getBytes();
    //3.Send base64 byte array to csharp
    Sender.sendData(b64Bytes);
}
```

}

CSHARP-Server:

```
class Program
{
    static string getStringFromBase64Bytes(byte[] base64Bytes)
    {
        //5.Base64 byte array to base64 string   
        string s64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64Bytes);      
        //6.Decode base64 string to utf string
        string utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(s64)); //Base64-String to UTF-8 String      
        return utf8;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Receiver mReceiver = new Receiver();
        //4.Receive base64 byte array
        byte[] data = mReceiver.waitForData();      

        string strDataTest = getStringFromBase64Bytes(data);
        //7.Get UTF-8 bytes
        byte[] fData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strDataTest);
        Console.WriteLine("DATA SIZE: " + fData.Length);
        //8.Save file
        File.WriteAllBytes("mFile.png", fData);

        mReceiver.closeAll();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show actual code - cleaned up see [MCVE] for guidance... (Also steps 4-7 are very strange - you may want to read something about dealing with base64 in C#)

Comment: Why are you doing all these conversions when you could also directly send and receive byte arrays? Oversimplified, you could just do `Sender.sendData(FileManager.readeFile())` and `File.WriteAllBytes("mFile.png", mReceiver.waitForData())`.

Comment: lol you are right.
But why can i do directly Sender.sendData and File.WriteAllBytes?
In csharp bytes are signed bytes and java are unsigned bytes?